# Count values in one column if dates fall in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, date-range, countif

Rewording the question as I've tried the responses (thank you very much for those) but they're not doing what I need.

Master tab has hundreds of candidate records on it from a large range of dates over the last year. I'm interested in 2 columns.
Col A contains the date the candidate took the exam
Col B contains the candidate grade (Distinction, Credit, Referral)

On a new tab, I need to report on how many Distinctions were achieved, how many Credits and how many referrals for last week only

This will need to be repeated each week on a new tab (difficult boss!) so I need to make it as easy to repeat as possible

Comment: I think a `CountIF()` should work?

Comment: I've been messing around with CountIF but can't get it to do what I want

Comment: Have a look now, `CountIFS()` was the way to go! ;)

Comment: "Master Tab", "difficult boss", "tabs" what hell are you talking about? do you have any code? any reference to a format (xls,csv,sql,etc) and or a language this corresponds to?

Answer (score 2):

Please list the grades uniquely (say in ColumnA starting in Row1) then in B1:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,">42005",Sheet1!A:A,"<42012",Sheet1!B:B,A1)
```

and copy down, where your data is assumed to be in Sheet1.  The numbers (`42005`, `42012`) are the numeric representations of the relevant date limits (eg `42005` is what my system shows for 1/1/2015 in Numeric format).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. So for column A1 to A6 I check whether the date falls between a certain range. In my case between `7/03/2015 and 19/03/2015`. Then I just want to count the items containing `DISTINCT/CREDIT/REFERRAL`.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6;"<20/03/2015";$A$1:$A$6;">06/03/2015";$B$1:$B$6;"DISTINCT")

=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6;"<20/03/2015";$A$1:$A$6;">06/03/2015";$B$1:$B$6;"CREDIT")

=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6;"<20/03/2015";$A$1:$A$6;">06/03/2015";$B$1:$B$6;"REFERRAL")
```